# Arrays in Mongo C++11 driver (new driver)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, c++11

I am using new Mongo C++11 driver (master branch) for my project and I have big problems with arrays. For example, when array is not empty (e.g. it is ["test"], when I get the data from Mongo with the driver with

```
`array::view empArray {doc["assignedEmployees"].get_array().value};`
```

end when I pass through the array with C++11 collection for loop I get three copies of `"test"`, and if the array is empty I get an infinite loop!

So, can you tell me if this is a bug inside driver, or I am using API the wrong way (since this driver is new, documentation is basically unexistant).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you still experience this issue on the 3.0.0-rc0 release of the C++11 driver?  If so, can you post the code that actually causes the infinite loop?

Comment: I am sorry to inform you that I have finished with that C++ project several months ago, but I am still using MongoDB, only this time in C#.